# Upgrade to Angular 13 issues

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I'm upgrading Angular 12 and VS 2019 .net Framework 4.7.2/C# application to Angular 13 (It was originally written in Angular 6 and upgraded from there)
First, it is taking too long to compile...like 45 min or so
After wasting a lot of time, I have realized that it starts taking too long to compile when I add references in angular.json to
bootstrap, popper, and jquery

Second, after it compiles, it does not create vendor.js. Is this something new in Angular 13 or am I missing something?

Third problem is that when I run the application, bootstrap dropdowns do not work, which I'm using in the menus or wherever I'm using toggle features like expand/collapse. From what I understand that is due to popper.js. Therefore, I removed reference to popper.js, and instead replaced bootstrap and popper.js with bootstrap.bundle.min.js. But none of the issues have resolved. Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Myproj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^11.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.4",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^6.2.0",
    "ajv": "^8.8.2",
    "ajv-keywords": "^5.1.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.27.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.27.1",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

And angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyProj": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "xlsx",
              "rxjs-compat",
              "rxjs/BehaviorSubject",
              "rxjs/add/observable/throw",
              "rxjs/add/operator/catch",
              "rxjs/Observable",
              "rxjs/operators/map",
              "rxjs/operators/tap"
            ],

            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "8kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Hierarchy:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "MyProj:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProj:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyProj",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
  }
}
```

It is not throwing any errors in the console using the Chrome dev tools. Please advise!

Comment: Use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-bootstrap)